# product of measure induces ? of linear operators

Tags: probability, measure-theory, operator-theory

Given two measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, we can form their product.  For simplicity, let's assume we're working over $\mathbb{R}$, and that these measures are absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue, so that we have corresponding densities $d_1$ and $d_2$.  This gives us corresponding linear operators
$$ L_1( c ) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_1(x) c(x) dx $$
and
$$ L_2( c ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_2(x) c(x) dx $$

The product $\mu_1 \times \mu_2$ induces a linear operator as well, more precisely

$$ L_3( c ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_1(x) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_2(y) c(x,y) dy\right) dx $$

Question 1: what is the name of the operation that gives the linear operator $L_3$ given the linear operators $L_1$ and $L_2$ ?

Question 2: If, instead of $2$ linear operators, one is instead given a vector of linear operators (coming from a vector of measures), does the corresponding operation have a (different) name?

Question 3: same as 1 and 2, but in the case where we have probability measures instead of just measures -- does the name change?

Comment: It's possible that in this context you should use different notation. Took me a while to figure out what that $\lambda$ meant... That's the lambda-calculus $\lambda$, right? Would probably be clearer if you just said "Defiine $L_1$ by $L_1c=\int etc$ as usual.

Comment: Sorry, too much time spent doing CS, that notation is now ingrained in me.  I'll edit, since it will indeed be clearer if I use the notation more usual in math.

Comment: To make this precise, you need to specify what vector spaces of functions you want the operators $L_i$ to act on.  However, generally you should find that $L_3$ is a sort of **tensor product** of $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: does the choice of vector space change the name of the constructions associated to $L_3$?  [I want to use this in several contexts, in each of which things are well defined, but no clear 'most general context'.  Thus my omission of those details]

Comment: @JacquesCarette: Not really.  But if, say, $L_1, L_2$ are acting on spaces $V_1, V_2$ respectively, their tensor product $L_1 \otimes L_2$ acts on the algebraic tensor product $V_1 \otimes V_2$.  Usually the space you want $L_3$ to act on is not simply $V_1 \otimes V_2$, but some larger space $V_3$ in which $V_1 \otimes V_2$ is dense.  In that case you would typically get that $L_3$ is the unique continuous extension of the tensor product $L_1 \otimes L_2$.  So the idea is the same, but details may vary between cases.